# Conditional formatting based on multiple values with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data that I am trying to filter data for based on a condition. Here is an example of data:

```
df <- data.frame("x" = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C"),
                 "y" = c("LL", "LL", "OO", "OO", "OO", "OO", "LL"))
```

I'm trying to filter the data such that, I only keep "A" because it is associated with both "LL" and "OO". I know this is a conditional filtering, but I can't figure out the conditions to code. This is what I have tried so far:

```
df %>%
 group_by(x) %>%
 filter(y == "LL" & y == "OO")
```

A Base solution or dplyr solution would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is `all`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(x) %>%
   filter(all(c("LL", "OO") %in% y))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   x [1]
#  x     y    
#  <fct> <fct>
#1 A     LL   
#2 A     LL   
#3 A     OO
```

---

In the OP's code, it is comparing `&` i.e. a single row can have both 'LL' and 'OO' which is not possible (unless these are two columns)

Comment: Thank you! This worked - I tried something similar `filter(all(y %in% c("LL", "OO"))` - I don't know why I didn't think to rearrange the arguments.

Comment: @Marshall `%in%` returns the logical vector wiith the length of the `lhs` element.  With all` on the 'y', it results in all TRUE because 'B' have 00 for all elements. and 'c' 'LL' only, as these elements are present in c('LL', 'OO')

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you for the explanation; I think my brain just got tired from staring at this problem for the last several hours, and just threw my hands up.

Comment: @Marshall Whenever I find something that is not making sense, I would take a step back and create a column (in this case) with `mutate` and see the output by splitting up the code i.e. `c("LL", "OO") %in% y`.  It is a much easier approach to understand the behavior of different functions